# Babel React transform : Property value expected type of string but got null

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have an application that is working great client side (transpiled and compiled with Webpack/Babel).

I'm trying to render this app server side with Node, but I'm getting this error :

```
TypeError: C:/[PROJECT_PATH]/src/_base/common/components/general/AComponent.js: Property value expected type of string but got null
at Object.validate (C:\[PROJECT_PATH]\node_modules\babel-types\lib\definitions\index.js:153:13)
at validate (C:\[PROJECT_PATH]\node_modules\babel-types\lib\index.js:269:9)
at Object.builder (C:\[PROJECT_PATH]\node_modules\babel-types\lib\index.js:222:7)
at File.<anonymous> (C:\[PROJECT_PATH]\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:329:56)
at File.addImport (C:\[PROJECT_PATH]\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:336:8)
at C:\[PROJECT_PATH]\node_modules\babel-plugin-react-transform\lib\index.js:257:46
at Array.map (native)
at ReactTransformBuilder.initTransformers (C:\[PROJECT_PATH]\node_modules\babel-plugin-react-transform\lib\index.js:255:40)
at ReactTransformBuilder.build (C:\[PROJECT_PATH]\node_modules\babel-plugin-react-transform\lib\index.js:164:41)
at PluginPass.Program (C:\[PROJECT_PATH]\node_modules\babel-plugin-react-transform\lib\index.js:331:17)
```

It happens on any component imported. 
I know the components themselves work because they do in client mode.

Here is my index.js (same babel config as in client side app) :

```
require('babel-register')({
  presets:["es2015", "stage-0",'react'],
  highlightCode: false,
  sourceMaps: "both",
  env: {
    development: {
      plugins: [
        'transform-decorators-legacy',
        ["react-transform", {
          transforms: [{
            imports: ['react'],
            locals: ['module']
          }]
        }]
      ]
    }
  }
});

require('./renderer.js');
```

Here is my renderer.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import Router, {match, RoutingContext } from 'react-router'

// this works :
import AnyActions from 'path/to/actions/AnyActions'

// this don't
import AnyComponent from 'path/to/any/component'
```

Everything else is commented out !

I tried to import this simple AComponent :

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'

export default class AComponent extends Component {

  render () { return (<p>Hello</p>)}

}
```

Same error !

I must miss something obvious ... but I don't see it !

Comment: What does your `C:/[PROJECT_PATH]/src/_base/common/containers/InitPage.js` look like? The file throws the error.

Comment: As I said, it happens on any component I try to import. I edited my message to clarify and added code of a test "AComponent" component ... If you can see something ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with my Babel's React-Transform incorrect configuration : I was specifiying import and locals without any transform name ...

Removing this part solved my problem. 
Here is my new index.js :

```
require('babel-register')({
  presets:["es2015", "stage-0",'react'],
  highlightCode: false,
  sourceMaps: "both",
  env: {
    development: {
      plugins: [
        'transform-decorators-legacy'
      ]
    }
  }
});

require('./renderer.js');
```